# How is a wild knot an embedding of $S^1$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, knot-theory

All knot texts say the definition of knots as an embedding of $S^1$ to $R^3$ give the (mostly unwanted) posibility of wild knots, I'm wondering how so.

The only way I can see it (and have found it) is too intuitive. If someone has an explicit function that works for some wild knot it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen https://wildandnoncompactknots.wordpress.com/tag/wild-knots/?

Comment: Which examples of wild knots do you know?

Comment: Martin thank you, that was actually very helpful to me!.

Comment: As for Paul, I do know of the classic wild knots with only one wild point, as well as some other much more complicated ones with only wild points. However I think the site I was given will suffice for this question, thank you!